# About value inserting

Tags: c#, html, sql-server

Hey guys I am trying to insert data from gridview label to my double defined entity, following is my line:

```
objInvoiceEntity.Invd_NetAmount = 
(((Label)(gvItems.Items[e.Item.ItemIndex].FindControl("lblNetTotalE"))).Text== "" 
? 0 :     
(((Label)
(gvItems.Items[e.Item.ItemIndex].FindControl("lblNetTotalE"))).Text));
```

It gives me error "Input string not in correct format".
What is wrong in above statement?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code is 'correct' the input value is invalid, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the string you pass to `Convert.ToDouble` is not in a format that can be parsed as a  double. Try setting a breakpoint on that line and see what the value of `Label` is.